# Space horror novel from 1990's (I think) where dead possess people and start to take over a planet

Tags: story-identification, space, horror

I'm looking for the name of a space horror novel from 1990's (I think) where the dead go to a very overcrowded limbo, and then the worst of them escape and possess people and start to take over a planet. Also features augmented mercenary soldiers who battle the possessed and a secondary storyline on a mega rich space ship.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the [Scientology space opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_opera_in_Scientology); perhaps it's something else by L. Ron Hubbard?

Answer (score 17):

This has to be [the Night's Dawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night%27s_Dawn_Trilogy) trilogy by Peter F. Hamilton!

> The sprawling narrative deals with a far future where humanity wages war against past souls flooding back into the land of the living via possession (Al Capone and Fletcher Christian are among the returnees). Hamilton's future is expansive and primarily optimistic, with huge sentient space-cities that can closely resemble a natural Eden.

Comment: Great books, too! Depending on where you buy the Night's Dawn "trilogy", it might be 3-6 books. It was 6 books (I think.) in the USA when I originally bought the first book, "The Reality Dysfunction" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reality_Dysfunction)

Comment: Can you add a little more context to your answer? While it's unlikely that Wikipedia will go away, they have been known to delete entries without warning and people can edit it, and providing some information in the answer preserves the rationale for this being said answer.

Comment: @SeanDuggan A simple google search for the series' name would lead to the same information that's in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @NewWorld:
It's an optional step to provide additional information, but the general policy is against "link-only" answers, so I generally suggest that people expand upon any such. :) I used to just do it until somebody yelled at me for trying to put words in their mouth.

Comment: @SeanDuggan If that's against policy then I would remove the link altogether; then it's not a link-only answer. It shouldn't bother anyone to take the extra 3 seconds to paste the name into google :)

Comment: @NewWorld: I think we'd be better off taking this to chat, or Meta, but I'm basically going by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer and the related discussion at http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5075/how-should-link-only-answers-be-flagged-here

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with the way the answer is after the edit (and hope the asker is too!). I didn't really see a way to expand the answer beyond the name of the series that wasn't rehashing Wikipedia, though, so I didn't. Over at SE I like to write answers that are a lot longer, but here there wasn't much to explain...